# Is it possible to access the history of calls done by LangChain LLM object to external API?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

When we create an Agent in LangChain we provide a Large Language Model object (LLM), so that the Agent can make calls to an API provided by OpenAI or any other provider. For example:

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)

agent = initialize_agent(
    [tool_1, tool_2, tool_3],
    llm,
    agent = 'zero-shot-react-description',
    verbose=True
    )
```

To address a single prompt of a user the agent might make several calls to the external API.

Is there a way to access all the calls made by LLM object to the API?

For example [here](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/models/llms/examples/token_usage_tracking.html) is described a way to get number of tokens in the request and in the response. What I need, instead, is the requests and the responses themselves (and not just number of tokens in them).

Answer (score 4):

The goal can be achieved by [writing a custom LLM wrapper](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/models/llms/examples/custom_llm.html).

So, I write the wrapper like this:

```
from langchain.llms.base import LLM
from typing import Optional, List, Mapping, Any

class CustomLLM(LLM):

    import langchain
    llm: langchain.llms.openai.OpenAI

    @property
    def _llm_type(self) -> str:
        return "custom"

    def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> str:

        reply = self.llm(prompt)

        f = open('calls.log', 'a')

        f.write('<request>\n')
        f.write(prompt)
        f.write('</request>\n')

        f.write('<response>\n')
        f.write(reply)
        f.write('</response>\n')
        f.close()

        return reply

    @property
    def _identifying_params(self) -> Mapping[str, Any]:
        """Get the identifying parameters."""
        return {"n": self.n}
```

Then I create my (wrapped) instance of the language model like this:

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature = 0)
wllm = CustomLLM(llm = llm)
```

By using this instance I get calls and responses of the language model saved in the "call.log" file!

Comment: I think the ask (and what I am looking for) is how to log the full network call HTTP request/response/headers etc. Any idea about that? Thanks

Comment: Any ideas how to wrap AzureChatOpenAI to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

While wrapping around the `LLM` class works, a much more elegant solution to inspect LLM calls is to use LangChain's [tracing](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/tracing/local_installation.html). To summarize the linked document, here's how to use it:

1. Run `langchain-server`
2. In a new terminal window, set the environment variable: `LANGCHAIN_HANDLER=langchain` and then run your LangChain code
3. Navigate to http://localhost:4173/ in your browser
4. Click "Session: default" and explore chain runs, including raw LLM calls.

Comment: The tracing option mentioned here seems to not exist anymore, their guide states you need to contact them & leads to 404 error.

Comment: I believe they have moved this to Langsmith which they've explicitly stated to be non-OSS